# Stats command shows undefined data in embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a little problem with my `stats` command, even I make an embed properties are `undefined`.

```
if (command == "stats") {
  let mcount = bot.users.size;
  let scount = bot.guilds.size;
  let tcount = bot.channels.filter(c => c.type === 'text').size;
  let vcount = bot.channels.filter(c => c.type === 'voice').size;
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setDescription(`:white_check_mark: Statistics of Tommy`)
    .setColor("2c2f33")
    .addField('**Users:**`' + `${mcount}` + '`')
    .addField('**Servers:**`' + `${scount}` + '`')
    .addField('**Text channels:**`' + `${tcount}` + '`')
    .addField('**Voice channels:**`' + `${vcount}` + '`');
  message.channel.send({
    embed
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your example is mostly working, but it shows the values on the same row as the field name, and the `undefined` text appears below each field name.

The reason is the `addField` method has a second parameter that sets the text (or field value) below the field name.

In your example, the calls to addField can be changed to:

```
.addField('**Users:**', `${mcount}`)
.addField('**Servers:**', `${scount}`)
.addField('**Text channels:**', `${tcount}`)
.addField('**Voice channels:**', `${vcount}`)
```

[image: Example output in Discord]

I found [this tutorial for RichEmbed and addField](https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/using-embeds-in-messages#richembed-builder) that helped me understand its usage.

Comment: It says
 .addField('**Users:**`', `${mcount}`, '`', false) \\ embed.fields[0].inline: Must be either true or false.

Comment: The third [addField](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=addField) parameter is optional and allows the field to appear side-by-side with adjacent inline fields. It has a default value of false.

Comment: In this case based on how he wanted the output inline is better